# I am trying to run akeneo using docker but it is giving me php version error

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, gnu-make, akeneo

Problem 1

```
 - Root composer.json requires akeneo/pim-community-dev dev-master -> satisfiable by akeneo/pim-community-dev[dev-master].
 - akeneo/pim-community-dev dev-master requires php 8.1.* -> your php version (8.0.22) does not satisfy that requirement.
```

I had a VM that had akeneo installed on it and it was working fine but as soon as i connected the VM to wifi it gave this error.
ps: i am using Vmware!

tried several solutions available and none of them worked! would really appreciate if someone can help me fix it!
Commands that i am using to run akeneo:

systemctl start docker
make dev

Comment: So what version of PHP do you have installed? `php -v` It sounds like you have PHP 8.0.22 installed and you need PHP 8.1

Comment: i have installed the newer version but it still isn't working! i think it has got to do something with the docker container

Comment: what command did you run to get this error?